# Flyway doesn't see create-table sql file if DB is not empty (has some tables)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, flyway

I am following J Thompson's udemy course on spring-data-jpa and hibernate. I am using `springboot 3.1.x` with `flyway-mysql 9.16.3` (maven dependency). My 'create table statements' are located in the path `src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__init_database.sql`

I do not want to clear my DB. My DB already has a table "xyz" too (which I do not want to drop).

Here's my `application-local.properties` file (using "local" profile):

```
#spring.datasource.username=bookadmin
spring.datasource.username=bookuser
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/bookdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC

# setting below prop is not needed anymore
#spring.jpa.database=mysql
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.sql.init.mode=always

#spring.liquibase.user=bookadmin
#spring.liquibase.password=password

spring.flyway.user=bookadmin
spring.flyway.password=password
# unlike what is in the tutorial, this seems to be necessary
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
```

I have added the last property on my own (without that an error like "history table not present" appears), after a bit of search. That one was not used in the course.

However, after that, I am getting flyway message "`Schema 'bookdb' is up to date. No migration necessary.`" on the console log output. But, the tables are not created in `bookdb` and so, hibernate validation fails on start-up.

If I clear my DB completely, then it works.

I have looked into a few answers, but unable to find any solution. Please help.